# Eu devo editar perguntas e respostas "erradas"?

Tags: debate, perguntas

Já me deparei com vários episódios em que uma pergunta é muito vaga ou baseada em opiniões, e possui erros de português e de nomes próprios. O mesmo acontece com respostas onde muitas vezes quem respondeu da uma resposta baseada mais no "achômetro" do que de fato no que a pergunta pede.

Um exemplo que abrange os dois casos é este:

> Pergunta: [upload automativo de arquivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22912/upload-de-arquivo-automatico)

Então, caso uma pergunta ou resposta não esteja de acordo com as "normas" do SO-pt, ainda assim eu posso editar os eventuais erros da mesma? Ou eu devo somente votar para fechar e/ou negativar? *(Vejam bem, eu falo de editar detalhes, e não toda a pergunta como um todo)*

Answer (score 5):

Até que ponto devemos editar uma questão é um assunto complexo. Eu ajustaria os erros de português e uma ou outra palavra sem sentido. Isso se a pergunta tiver algum sentido no fundo.

Neste caso em questão, com um pouco de esforço é possível entender o que o usuário quer. Provavelmente ele tem um formulário que precisa ser atualizado em algumas situações, tais como eventos que não podem ser Ajax. O problema é que quando isso ocorre, alguns campos de upload enviam os arquivos e os mesmos não aparecem mais.

Como eu já trabalhei mais de uma vez com formulários de uploads múltiplos eu entendo perfeitamente o problema, mas também não é algo fácil de fazer e depende muita da estrutura do sistema.

Enfim, minha opinião é que essa pergunta poderia ser editada e a comunidade decidiria se você foi longe demais ou não.

Particularmente, não votaria nesse caso pelo que mencionei acima, mas pediria para o OP postar o código para que ele pudesse ser ajudado mais efetivamente.

Answer (score 5):

Eu sou da opinião que deve-se fechar esse tipo de pergunta *o mais rápido possível*. Isso evita respostas "achômetro" e obriga o autor a esclarecer sua pergunta. Dependendo do caso, também negativar, pois isso sinaliza ao resto da comunidade que aquela pergunta tem problemas.

Nesse caso específico, não entendo quem dá +1... Acabo de fazer -1 pra equilibrar no zero pelo menos.

Answer (score 2):

No caso particular a ser discutido, a pergunta está realmente pouco clara. As edições realizadas reformularam o texto mas em nada contribuíram para tornar o problema claro e assim possibilitar uma resposta.

Pelas respostas apresentadas, denota-se que existe uma divergência de interpretações, e a minha leitura da pergunta vem adicionar mais uma versão da possível intenção do OP.

[Pelo que li:](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/22912/1)

> Preciso fazer com que ao atualizar a pagina, o input file ja vem carregado com os arquivos que serão salvos no banco, lembrando que os arquivos terão o mesmo nome..

Fiquei com a ideia que a intenção aqui é ter os ficheiros anexados ao formulário quando a página sofre um *refresh*. Onde eu iria sugerir uma solução semelhante à [resposta do @utluiz♦](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/22984/223) mas com `input[type="hidden"]` para conter no formulário a informação dos ficheiros, conforme parece ser a intenção do OP.

Efetivamente, quer com esta quer com outras perguntas neste formato, eu sou da opinião que sem código que ilustre o que está a ser desenvolvido e ajude a criar um ponto-de-partida para as respostas é difícil fornecer qualquer tipo de ajuda. Vamos ter muitas respostas, todas a sugerir soluções e com muita sorte uma dessas respostas irá de encontro com a necessidade do OP (este último cenário é muito raro de se verificar).

### Ação

Comentar na pergunta que o OP deverá atualizar a mesma de forma a obter ajuda.
Esperar um tempo e se não editada, iniciar o processo de suspensão.

### Editar ou não este tipo de perguntas

Editar para que? Criar histórico de revisões sobre algo que não está claro e que vai continuar a não estar claro até o OP proceder à adição de conteúdos que clarifiquem o problema, não beneficia ninguém...