# Devo evidenciar o problema da pergunta com uma edição?

Tags: debate, perguntas, edição

Algumas vezes me deparo com uma situação onde a pergunta descreve o erro de forma razoável, o código fonte não apresenta erro de sintaxe ou de lógica.

A próxima suspeita é que deve ser um problema de ambiente, as vezes é impossível de descobrir outras pequena lista ação já delimitam a situação adversa. Olhem essas  gêmeas [1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69103/preparedstatement-n%C3%A3o-est%C3%A1-funcionando/69107#comment141192_69103) e [2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80857/erro-na-base-de-dados-pdo#comment164169_80862) (peço que leiam a pergunta os comentários das duas)

Deve editar a pergunta para evidenciar o problema e de quebra casar a pergunta com a resposta?

Fiz um pesquisa sobre questões parecidas achei essas duas mas parecem não tocar no assunto.

[Eu devo editar perguntas e respostas “erradas”?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1630/91)

[Editar pergunta para adicionar detalhes informados através de comentário](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3997/91)

Comment: O título não está muito bom se alguém tiver um melhor ... pensei em: editar a pergunta descrevendo o problema real(de ambiente) no lugar do original ou editar uma pergunta para adequa-la à uma resposta. ... sei la

Comment: Acredito que a edição sirva para corrigir erros de sintaxe, adicionar formatação e remover ruídos, de certa forma melhorando o entendimento que se possa ter da questão - mas sem alterar seu conteúdo ou sentido originais. Como exatamente você evidenciaria o problema, sem quebrar essas regras?

Comment: Eu diria que se ficar mais fácil/rápido identificar o problema na pergunta o edit é muito bem vindo. Perguntas respondidas e aceites têm (quase sempre) o problema identificado e resolvido. Clarificar a pergunta é fazer um favor e ajudar futuros utilizadores com o mesmo problema.

Comment: @Sergio Concordo - porém, nas duas questões, o único problema ao meu ver, são os títulos, pois em baixo, os OPs clarificaram: `Porém não salva os dados no banco.` e `Não da nenhum erro, nada, simplesmente não insere.`

Comment: Por sinal, a sua resposta na [questão do rogue_psycho](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80857/4816) está incorreta, não é? Ela está como aceita, mas a solução foi dada nos comentários - esse é um problema maior do que ter dificuldade em entender a questão... ;)

Comment: @Daniel Gomes o problema das duas perguntas é que passam longe do problema real.

Answer (score 8):

Mesmo plenamente ciente do risco de passar instruções gerais que podem ser tomadas como regras ou ordens...

### *Quase* sempre que você vir algo que possa ser melhorado, melhore

É um ponto que pode ser discutido eternamente mas minha opinião é de que, dentre todas as características do nosso site, a edição colaborativa é a mais poderosa e a mais útil para manter a qualidade do site.

Isso porque *idealmente* o AP deveria inserir todas as informações na pergunta, e editá-la sempre que algo mais surgisse nos comentários, mas isso nem sempre acontece. É normal e esperado. Não adianta passar a vida inteira reclamando que o AP não aprende nunca, se é um problema que você pode resolver (e de quebra ensinar através de exemplo) com menos esforço do que é necessário para fazer cara feia.

Na [primeira pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/69103/12), o AP forneceu [alguns](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69103/preparedstatement-n%C3%A3o-est%C3%A1-funcionando/69107#comment141191_69103) [detalhes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69103/preparedstatement-n%C3%A3o-est%C3%A1-funcionando/69107#comment141193_69103) que podiam
facilmente ir para a pergunta, o que ajudaria todo mundo a entender e resolver o problema, e todas as próximas pessoas com a mesma dúvida a identificar se aquela pergunta atende aos mesmos requisitos que eles tem.

Editar com boas intenções raramente vai piorar as coisas. Ao passo que nunca editar é uma maneira muito eficiente de não melhorar o site. Como diria [Wayne Gretzky](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayne_Gretzky), o Jon Skeet do hóquei no gelo:

> Você erra 100% dos chutes que não dá